# differences between NSArray and CCArray

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray

What are the differences between NSArray and CCArray? Also, in what cases will one be preferred to the other with respect to game programming?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CCArray emulates NSMutableArray. It is a wrapper around a C array (memory buffer). It was developed and is used internally by cocos2d because NSMutableArray was deemed too slow. However the performance improvement is minimal. Any use cases (features) of CCArray that cocos2d itself doesn't use remain a potential source of issues, including weird and hard to debug issues or terrible performance characteristics.

The most important performance critical aspect is reading the array sequential. In [my latest tests](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/03/confirmed-arc-slow/) that's an area where CCArray (no longer?) excels. Specifically fast enumeration: NSMutableArray is around 33 times faster!

CCArray is a perfect example why one should not reinvent the wheel, specifically when it comes to storage classes when there is already a stable, proven, and fast solution available (NSMutableArray). Any speed advantage it may have once had is long gone. What remains is a runtime behavior you will not want to deal with, including some extremely bad performance characteristics (insertion, fast enumeration).

Long story short: **do not use CCArray in your own code!** Treat CCArray like an internal, private class not to be used in user code (except where unavoidable, ie children array).

NSMutableArray is THE array reference implementation everyone should be using because it's extremely well tested, documented, and stable (both in terms of runtime behavior and speed).

Answer (score 2):

Check it....

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/09/array-performance-comparison-carray-ccarray-nsarray-nsmutablearray/

Hope this help
  Enjoy Programming

Answer (score 1):

CCArray
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d9/d2e/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_array.html

In cocos2d-x CCArray is mutable, i.e. you can add elements to it. To create CCArray instance without capacity, you can use CCArray::array() constructor. CCMutableArray is template-based container that can store objects of the same type. CCArray stores objects as CCObject instances, so you have to cast them after getting from CCArray instance

The NSArray class contains a number of methods specifically designed to ease the creation and manipulation of arrays within Objective-C programs.